# How to access tools:sample data from Kotlin/Java classes?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Sample data was one of the great inventions from Android Studio team. It makes design development pretty much easy. So my actual question is, How can we access sample data from Java/Kotlin classes instead of XML.

Comment: you can't access

Comment: No!  you can't....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can we access sample data from Java/Kotlin classes

You cannot. The tools namespace is not available runtime. See from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes):

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I wanted some random fake data inside my application as the part of the development. Instead of some data faker library, I just want to make sure whether tools may come in handy or not